# How do I send API key to Destiny2 API?

Tags: jquery, api, request-headers

I am trying to access the Destiny2 API but I am getting a 'no API Key' message. The key is valid as I have used it in Postman. Am I setting the header correctly? The code I wrote is below. I am passing a valid username to the function.

```js
function destinyId(username) {
  var uri = 'https://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/SearchDestinyPlayer/-1/' + username + '/';
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function(request) {
      request.setRequestHeader('X-API-Key', myKey);
    },
    url: uri,
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the jQuery code you've shown, the header will be set. The issue may lie in the format of `myKey`. Are you certain it exactly matches what you use in Postman? What is the response you get back?

Comment: I literally copy pasted from postman. I get a reply Failed to load resource
{"ErrorCode":2102,"ThrottleSeconds":0,
"ErrorStatus":"ApiKeyMissingFromRequest",
"Message":"Please add valid X-API-Key header to request.
Visit https://www.bungie.net/developer for details.","MessageData":{}}

Comment: Is `myKey` in your code above the function? How is it defined?

Comment: I originally had the key directly in the beforeSend function but moved it to the myKey variable for this post.

Comment: Try using `headers` instead. It should be the same output, but worth trying as a last resort. See the jQuery example in the docs: http://destinydevs.github.io/BungieNetPlatform/docs/Getting-Started

Comment: I have already tried headers: {"x-api-key", myKey}, with the same results.

Comment: In which case I'm afraid we can't help. There must be some difference between the Postman request and the JS. Only you can determine what that is

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'll keep at it.

Comment: Solved. The problem was bungie.net requires an origin header for web browser api calls.

Comment: Don't forget to add your Origin Header in the portal. I think you only need them for browser-based requests. Server-side won't need them.